# Как посчитать количество аргументов, вводимых в функцию при помощи *?

Tags: python, функции

Есть следующее задание:

> Напишите функцию, которая будет возвращать числом количество
> аргументов, которые подали ей на вход.

Я вроде бы понял, как мне реализовать это в рамках базы: подсчёта длины списка, написал следующее:

```
def args_counter(*args):
  value = []
  for el in args:
    value.append(el)
  print("Вот, сколько Вы ввели аргументов: ", len(value))

for_count = input("Введите Ваши аргументы (через запятаю с пробелом): ")
not_yet_counted = for_count.split(", ")

args_counter(not_yet_counted)
```

Но почему-то при активации кода с каким бы то ни было отличным от одного кол-вом аргументов, все равно выводится 1, не понимаю, почему так. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому-что, при `args_counter(not_yet_counted)` вы только в первый аргумент передали список
А чтобы этот список распаковать в аргументы, используйте `*`, тогда в каждый аргумент функции будет передаваться элемент списка:

```
args_counter(*not_yet_counted)
```

Кст, можно сразу размер `args` выводить:

```
def args_counter(*args):
    print("Вот, сколько Вы ввели аргументов:", len(args))
```